# How to use an Azure blob-only storage account with Azure Functions - Trying to create blob snapshot

Tags: azure, azure-functions, snapshot, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage-account

I'm trying to set up a function to take a snapshot of a blob container every time a change is pushed to it. There is some pretty simple functionality in Azure Functions to do this, but it only works for general purpose storage accounts. I'm trying to do this with a blob only storage account. I'm very new to Azure so I may be approaching this all wrong, but I haven't been able to find much helpful information. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Please edit your question and include more details. For example, include the code to take snapshot. What happens when you try to take a snapshot for blobs in blob storage account? Are you getting any error? In its current state, there's not much information available in the question to provide meaningful solution.

Comment: You mean you have a `blobtrigger` function ? If so you need to understand that Azure functions needs a storage account because it uses storage table to persist data. This is configured using `AzureWebJobsStorage` and `AzureWebJobsDashboard` but you can configure your `blobtrigger` function to use a different connectionstring. Does it make sense for you ? Would you like some code sample ?

Comment: Yes it is a blob trigger. How would I go about making the function use a different connection string? According to Microsoft documentation the storage account would have to be general purpose to connect to the function trigger. In the UI my storage container is never an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @joy-wang mentioned, the [Azure Functions Runtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-runtime-overview) requires a [general purpose storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-account-options).

A general purpose storage account is required to configure the **AzureWebJobsStorage** and the **AzureWebJobsDashboard** settings ([local.settings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local#local-settings-file) or [Appsettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings) Blade in the Azure portal):

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "my general purpose storage account connection string",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "my general purpose storage account connection string",
    "MyOtherStorageAccountConnectionstring": "my blob only storage connection string"
  }
}
```

If you want to create a [BlobTrigger Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-storage-blob-triggered-function), you can specify another connection string and create a snapshot everytime a blob is created/updated:

```
[FunctionName("Function1")]
public static async Task Run([BlobTrigger("test-container/{name}",
        Connection = "MyOtherStorageAccountConnectionstring")]CloudBlockBlob myBlob,
        string name, TraceWriter log)
{
    log.Info($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name}");
    await myBlob.CreateSnapshotAsync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, @Thomas , I have test your code, it works fine. Actually, I have tried this method before, but I made a silly mistake somewhere else in my code, so it gave me an error. Thank you for sharing, hope it can help more community members.

Answer (score 0):

**In the Visual Studio:**

I have tried to create **snapshot** for a **blob-only storage**
named `joyblobstorage` , but it failed. I supposed you should get the same error in the screenshot.

[image]

As the error information says `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Storage account 'joyblobstorage' is of unsupported type 'Blob-Only/ZRS'. Supported types are 'General Purpose'.`

**In the portal:**

I try to create a **Function App** and **use the existing Storage**, but it could not find my **blob-only storage account**. Azure Function setup in portal should not allow we to select a blob-only storage account. Please refer to the screenshot.

[image]

**Conclusion**:

It is **not possible** to create **snapshot** for a **blob-only storage**. In the official documentation, you could see the [Storage account requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-function-app-portal#storage-account-requirements).

> When creating a function app in App Service, you **must** create or link to a **general-purpose** Azure Storage account that supports Blob, Queue, and Table storage.

Also, in the [App settings reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#azurewebjobsstorage), you could see

> **AzureWebJobsStorage**
>
> The Azure Functions runtime uses this storage account connection string for all functions except for HTTP triggered functions. The storage account **must** be a **general-purpose** one that supports blobs, queues, and tables.
>
> **AzureWebJobsDashboard**
>
> Optional storage account connection string for storing logs and displaying them in the Monitor tab in the portal. The storage account **must** be a **general-purpose** one that supports blobs, queues, and tables.

Here is the [Feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/355860-azure-functions/suggestions/17452762-azure-function-setup-in-portal-should-not-allow-yo), **Azure App Service Team** has explained the **requirements on storage account**, you could refer to it.

Comment: This is not exactly true, Azure functions required a general-purpose storage account but you can configure a blob trigger for any kind of storage account, you need to specify a different connection string.

Comment: @Thomas I used the connection string of the blob-only storage，but it failed like the screenshot.

Comment: Yes you need a general purpose storage account to configure the `AzureWebJobsStorage` and `AzureWebJobsDashboard` settings but you can use a blob only storage account for other thing like blob trigger

Comment: Sure I will post something tomorrow, it is almost time to go tbed here.

Comment: I've added an answer